# Generate child row under a parent row in html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I am unable to create a html table ,where there will be child rows under a parent row and each row will be considered a master row under a table .I am not good at html what i can do make a html table and remove the border of the rows but actually **i can make only a simple table which is useless Thats why i am not adding any code ,I am sorry for that** .I have attached an image of the table i want to create .here "A" is the parent row and "A1","A2","A3" are child row And A will be the parent row because further I will write serverside code based on this table .
[image]

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>A1</td>
<td>A2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="noBorder">
<td>B</td>
<td>B1</td>
<td>B2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>C</td>
<td>C1</td>
<td>C2</td>
</tr>
</table>

 //**Css
 table, tr, td {
 border: 3px solid red;
 }
 tr.noBorder td {
 border: 0;
 }
```

Please Help needed from the experts. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rowspan will work for you

Please refer to the following

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sr</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">1</td>
                <td >Hello</td>
                <td >Hello How Are You</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hello 2</td>
                <td>Hello How Are You 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hello 3</td>
                <td>Hello How Are You 3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">2</td>
                <td >Hello</td>
                <td >Hello How Are You</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hello 2</td>
                <td>Hello How Are You 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hello 3</td>
                <td>Hello How Are You 3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for  such a simple solution

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th {
  padding: 8px
}

table td {
  padding: 8px
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
    <th>H3</th>
    <th>H4</th>
    <th>H5</th>
    <th>H6</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">A</td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">B</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

you will use rowspan, see example below!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Document sans nom</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>H1</td>
    <td>H2</td>
    <td>H3</td>
    <td>H4</td>
    <td>H5</td>
    <td>H6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">A</td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">B</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">C</td>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C2</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```